# How to show WSDL for a web service that was build with Perl

Tags: web-services, perl, wsdl, soaplite

I made a web service before in PHP and when i went to the server link to the webservice it would build and show me the WSDL for it. I had to recreate the web service in perl (as a .cgi file), but now when i go to the link for the webservice i am not getting back a wsdl for it. What do I need to do in order to build a wsdl for my perl based web-service? I am use teh SOAP::Lite library for my webservice.

Answer (score 1):

Quoting [SOAP::Schema](http://p3rl.org/SOAP%3a%3aSchema#SOAP%3a%3aSchema%3a%3aWSDL):

> At present, the SOAP::Lite toolkit supports only loading of service descriptions in the WSDL syntax.

Use a different module, such as [XML::Compile::WSDL11](http://p3rl.org/XML%3a%3aCompile%3a%3aWSDL11), to build a WSDL resource.